# Browsers don't identify dual monitors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, browser

When I share my screen on Hangouts, the other person sees both of my screen combined as one, Ideally the browser should ask which monitor to share.

I tried using Chrome and Firefox to share my screen both show the same behaviour. Is the any workaround to this, or any tool which possibly can solve this issue ?